# Haskell: Type declaration in `where`

Tags: haskell, types

I have an example of function, in which I can't write a type in `where` clause. `replace` is a function, that replaces all Xs by Ys in a given list.

```
replace :: (Eq a) => a -> a -> [a] -> [a]
replace x y xs = map helper xs
  where
    helper :: (Eq a) => a -> a
    helper = (\el -> if el == x then y else el)
```

When I try to compile this function I get an error:

```
ProblemsArithmetics.hs:156:31:
Could not deduce (a ~ a1)
from the context (Eq a)
  bound by the type signature for
             replace :: Eq a => a -> a -> [a] -> [a]
  at ProblemsArithmetics.hs:152:12-41
or from (Eq a1)
  bound by the type signature for helper :: Eq a1 => a1 -> a1
  at ProblemsArithmetics.hs:155:15-30
  ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for replace :: Eq a => a -> a -> [a] -> [a]
      at ProblemsArithmetics.hs:152:12
  ‘a1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
       the type signature for helper :: Eq a1 => a1 -> a1
       at ProblemsArithmetics.hs:155:15
Relevant bindings include
  el :: a1 (bound at ProblemsArithmetics.hs:156:16)
  helper :: a1 -> a1 (bound at ProblemsArithmetics.hs:156:5)
  xs :: [a] (bound at ProblemsArithmetics.hs:153:13)
  y :: a (bound at ProblemsArithmetics.hs:153:11)
  x :: a (bound at ProblemsArithmetics.hs:153:9)
  replace :: a -> a -> [a] -> [a]
    (bound at ProblemsArithmetics.hs:153:1)
In the second argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘x’
In the expression: el == x
```

At the same time, if I omit

```
helper :: (Eq a) => a -> a
```

the code is compiled fine.

While I understand the logic behind it (`a` in `replace` type declaration and `a` in `helper` type declaration are different `a`s), and there are at least 2 workarounds (omit type declaration or pass `x` and `y` as parameters to `helper` function), my question is:

Is there any way to tell the compiler that I mean the same type in both type declarations?

Comment: Yes: https://wiki.haskell.org/Scoped_type_variables

Comment: Try adding `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}`. I cannot test now, anyone is free to turn my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you enable [`ScopedTypeVariables`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#scoped-type-variables) and introduce a type variable with a `forall`, then it becomes visible in the inner scope.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

replace :: forall a. (Eq a) => a -> a -> [a] -> [a]
replace x y xs = map helper xs
  where
    helper :: a -> a
    helper = (\el -> if el == x then y else el)
```